# Why does my Kill-a-Watt read Power of only half the Voltage times Current?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, ac

My [Kill-a-Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/p4400.html) is displaying that its output is 120 V, 0.16 A, and 10 W.

I'm confused... I thought P = V × I from basic EE. Why do I see only half the expected value here?

(This is a USB charger, and I'm trying to calculate the charger output current indirectly.)

Comment: Your math is confused.  Vrms * Irms = 120V * 0.16A = 20VA.  And 10 != 2 * 20.  (Which is lucky, because a power factor of 2.0 is impossible)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Fixed the typo

Answer (score 3):

P = V × I only holds if I and V include phase information (i.e. are complex numbers), whereas the "V" and "I" displayed are actually the magnitudes of these variables.
The value we want to use is the P that is displayed, since it includes phase information.
So, in this case, the USB output current should be 10 W / 5 V × *[efficiency]*.

Comment: Kill-a-Watt is supposedly to display input power, not output power.  Due to efficiency, the output current will be less than 2 A, possibly by as much as half.  The difference ends up as heat in the charger.

Comment: The portion of your answer concerning phase is correct, but runs into the problem in the presentation of your question where you claim that the power factor is 2.0 -- There's no phase leading to a power factor > 1.0, because power factor is `cos(Vphase-Iphase)`

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hm, looking at it again it seems correct. "Possibly by as much as half?" No way, I don't believe that... that'd be nuts. I don't think the difference is measurable at all. Is there anything actually wrong with the answer? Looking at it again I think the only mistake was in the question, but the answer got downvoted instead of the question which is confusing...

Comment: It's not the Kill-a-Watt that's burning power (plus, it should show its own output not its input).  Consider the Kill-a-Watt reading to be a good measure of the power into the AC input of your USB charger.  Then the USB charger loses some of that power to heat, and the remainder goes out the USB port.  Some of that is lost in the USB cable, and the rest goes into your device being charged.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sorry, yes, I got that and then somehow I momentarily forgot that you were talking about the adapter. But again, I don't think that's right... in fact the adapter actually says its USB output is supposed to be 5 V and 2 A, so I think any loss due to it is negligible here...

Comment: For your "don't think the difference is measurable", check out [some data from someone who measured](http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html)  As a rule of thumb you can expect about 70% efficiency from small AC/DC converters.

Comment: The "2A" rating on the charger is the peak supported, but the actual amount being drawn depends on the device.  The voltage is (mostly) pushed by the charger, the current is (mostly) pulled by the device, not pushed.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ahh... that's where the problem is. Even though I knew that part, I assumed since the charger came with the phone and the phone was low on battery, the phone would draw maximum power. Didn't realize that probably wasn't the case, but that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In AC circuits there's an important measurement that your Kill-a-Watt might not be giving you, *the Power Factor*. See with an AC circuit, peak current might not occur at the same time as peak voltage (this is true for pretty much anything not an ideal resistor). Resistive loads burn power but capacitive and inductive loads don't, they grab a bit of power then give it right back again, they 'hot potato' energy back and forth down the line. These "reactive" loads draw current but not (average) power, the fact that you're getting V*I > P means that your load is partially reactive as some of the energy being drawn is coming in then going right back out again (reactive power) and some is being used by the load to do some *real* work (called, funnily enough, *real power*). Real power is the instantaneous product of V and I as opposed to the average product of V and I (which is called the *apparent power* as it is the sum of real and reactive power and represents the, well... *apparent* power draw of the device). The power factor is a measure of the amount of Real to Reactive power and is the cosine of the phase angle between the AC current and the AC voltage (this only holds if the two are at the same frequency).